# Do values in `sys.dm_os_wait_stats` reset to 0 or stop accumulating when they hit the max value?

Tags: sql-server, dmv

When looking at [sys.dm_os_wait_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-wait-stats-transact-sql), the following columns are defined as `BIGINT`

- waiting_tasks_count
- wait_time_ms
- max_wait_time_ms

If any of those values go above `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, do the counters reset to 0, or simply stop counting?

It's unclear from the table definition what goes on behind the scenes:

```
sp_helptext 'sys.dm_os_wait_stats'
```

Returns:

```
CREATE VIEW sys.dm_os_wait_stats AS  
 SELECT *  
 FROM OpenRowset(TABLE SYSWAITSTATS)
```

So that's a bit of a black box.

There are some DMVs where large numbers can turn negative. One example of this is the `total_elapsed_time` column in `dm_exec_requests`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-wait-stats-transact-sql):

> In SQL Server the wait-time counters are bigint values and therefore
>   are not as prone to counter rollover as the equivalent counters in
>   earlier versions of SQL Server.

I've seen this with earlier version of SQL Server where rollover happened and you'd get negative numbers because the values are signed.

I took a look at the source code and indeed these are 8-byte signed values. Since this is all C++, I created a simple repro:

```
#include "stdint.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int64_t i8 = 0;
    cout << "Size of integer: " << sizeof(i8) << " bytes." << endl;
    cout << "Max Value: " << INT64_MAX << endl;
    i8 = INT64_MAX + 1;
    cout << "Value of MAX + 1: " << i8 << endl;
    cin;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is similar to what I experienced in previous versions of SQL Server, the signed value is rolled over. Note that if you compile this, you should get a compiler warning that there will be rollover - I received [compiler warning 4307](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C4307)&rd=true).

Output of above:

```
Size of integer: 8 bytes.
Max Value: 9223372036854775807
Value of MAX + 1: -9223372036854775808
```

I'm **NOT** stating this is exactly how SQL Server works in all and every case as there are many nuances... but this *should* be a similar approximation.

**What does this all really mean?**

I highly doubt, as Aaron has said, that you'll ever encounter rollover on the 64-bit values in the current hardware climate. If you did, it would be easy to spot and really be more of reporting inaccuracy than any real issue in my opinion.